# FTP files via CMD along with date created

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a batch file that ftp all the files in a particular directory on my server but when it is done with FTP, the date created of the file changes. Is there any way I can preserve this or perhaps concatenate it along with the file name? I need this info for further processing.

Here is my batch file code:

```
@echo off
echo open *ip* >> temp.txt
echo *user* >> temp.txt
echo *pass* >> temp.txt
echo cd *directory* >> temp.txt
echo lcd *localdirectory* >> temp.txt
echo prompt no >> temp.txt
echo mget *.q* >> temp.txt
echo quit >> temp.txt
ftp -s:temp.txt
del temp.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows built-in FTP client (`ftp.exe`) cannot preserve timestamp of remote file when downloading (or uploading).

You have to use another FTP client. Most other FTP clients do preserve the timestamp.

---

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) use the following batch file (`download.bat`):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=download.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "cd /directory" ^
    "lcd c:\localdirectory" ^
    "get *.q*" ^
    "exit"
```

See also [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

You can also have [WinSCP generate the script file or even the batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*